# CREATE PROCEDURE being run repeatedly on SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I'm trying to diagnose a performance issue on a SQL Server 2014 database using the following query, which I would credit to its original author if I could remember the source:

```
SELECT TOP 50
    st.text,
    qp.query_plan,
    qs.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY total_worker_time DESC
GO
```

I'm very concerned because I see a query in the results with text = `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]...` with an execution count in the "many thousand times" range.  Some of our code has a database upgrade script that contains the query, but to the best of my ability to test, it should not have run more than once (and even if a bug was causing the script to run repeatedly, there should be many other similar statements with the same execution count, which isn't happening.)

Is there a logical reason why this query might be getting run repeatedly?  Would `EXEC MyProcedure` show up as `CREATE PROCEDURE` in this query due to the fact that the query plan is being reused?  Is there a possibility that a failure when creating a procedure would cause SQL Server to retry it continually?  Can databases become haunted by malevolent ghosts?

Any troubleshooting advice is appreciated!

Comment: You are asking us to explain to you why a query is being repeatedly on your system with absolutely no way of us have a chance at answering this.

Comment: @SeanLange - Be more optimistic!  By your logic, I also have no way of answering this since lots of stuff goes on that I'm unaware of.  In the last paragraphs, I asked two specific questions about SQL Server behavior that might point me in the right direction, and then asked for "troubleshooting advice", ie, "you can try this to test for X"

Comment: OK. You asked four questions in the last paragraph. I will answer them in order. 1) Potentially but impossible to say without a lot more information and understanding of your environment. 2) No. 3) No. 4) No, but that is hilarious.

Answer (score 2):

This thread says the CREATE is expected when a sproc is executed.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/cpu-100-current-queries-show-create-procedure

Specifically, the comments by GilaMonster:

> The procedures are not being created. They are being executed.
>
> When you execute a procedure, the sql_text DMV shows the create so that you can use the statement offsets to get the exact statement executing.